# Variable inside array in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I have some problem here with some code in Wordpress.

```
<?php
$output="";
foreach($type2 as $t) {$output.= "'".$t->slug."',"; }
echo $output;
?>
```

This code outputs this:

```
'cocinas','banos-y-spa','mobiliario-de-hogar',
```

The problem comes when I want to use $output to put it in an array:

```
<?php
if(is_tax( 'type', array ($output))) {
putRevSlider(get_queried_object()->slug);}
?>
```

The strange thing is that this one does work ok, although it's not useful, because I need it to be dynamic:

```
<?php
if(is_tax( 'type', array ('cocinas','banos-y-spa','mobiliario-de-hogar',))) {
putRevSlider(get_queried_object()->slug);}
?>
```

Why doesn't $output work inside the array if it has the same values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you converting array content into string.

Anyways, convert the `$type2` into the format you are looking for:

```
<?php
$output=array();
foreach($type2 as $t) {
    $output[] =  $t->slug;
}
?>
```

This will provide you appropriate array which you can use directly in your `is_tax()` function.

```
<?php
if(is_tax( 'type', $output)) {
putRevSlider(get_queried_object()->slug);}
?>
```

Comment: OMG!
Thanks! This works fine.

The reason I did it wrong is because I am not a programmer, but I am doing my best ;)

Thanks